# Working code suddenly stopped working - why?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have been using a ASYNC TASK to send or fetch the data from my app to the database and vice-versa via REST API. The Code i have been using for my few projects(completed) is what i use in other new projects too.I have now created a new project and the working async code is not fetching data anymore, but the same code i paste in any previous projects, it works well. I have a new project starting tomorrow and i want the code i am ease to use works well in new projects too. To be considered that  INTERNET PERMISSION ADDED IN MANIFEST..
The code in MainActivity.java that should display the Toast from database on postExecute

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String name;
    ArrayList<String> NAME=new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new getpostcount().execute();
    }

    public class getpostcount extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String db_url;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //   Toast.makeText(newsFeed.this, "Loading........", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db_url = "http://testprasis.000webhostapp.com/getshopname.php";

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(db_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);

                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                String data = stringBuilder.toString().trim();

                String json;

                InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                int size = stream.available();
                byte[] buffer1 = new byte[size];
                stream.read(buffer1);
                stream.close();

                json = new String(buffer1, "UTF-8");
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

                for (int i = 0; i <= jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (jsonObject.getString("id") != null) {
                        name = jsonObject.getString("shop_name");

                        NAME.add(name);


                    }
                }


                return null;


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
//
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,NAME.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
2019-11-27 17:13:00.044 26790-26790/com.sheershakx.hisab E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sheershakx.hisab, PID: 26790
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.sheershakx.hisab.MainActivity$getpostcount.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:119)
        at com.sheershakx.hisab.MainActivity$getpostcount.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:38)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:180)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Comment: internet permission ?

Comment: the idea of copy pasting code only works when you understand the code. even then, copy pasting code isn't really a good approach.

Comment: is internet permission in granted  in manifest.xml?

Comment: @a_local_nobody i know the mechanism of the copied code, i can try new code , but its a search for answer that how a working code suddenly stop working on an condition that it works fine with older projecets and not in new?

Comment: @ManjeetBrar yes bruh,its added already

Comment: @VishvenduPalawat yes bruh, added

Comment: post the error or stacktrace?

Comment: @mudit_sen, i just added, please go through it buddy

Comment: Look further up in your logcat for those stack traces you're printing in all those `catch` blocks.

Comment: I think Your URL which is fetching the data is not returning response so please check first that  NAME.add(name) is getting filled or not.

Comment: `I have a new project starting tomorrow and i want the code i am ease to use works well in new projects too.` If you want more resilient code, then you might want to consider finding the new, up to date options, such as https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: @Sheershak just checked. Everything work.

Comment: @Eugene Troyanakii  yes there isnt a code mistake i know but why is it not running on new projects?

Comment: @VishvenduPalawat it is returuning a response Eugene Trotanskii ran the code succesfully, is there android studio error or something??

Comment: Please don't edit your question to add SOLVED to the title or body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why it didn't work all of the sudden?**

Actually it will work but on Android version lower that `Android P`.
Because `Android P` uses `HTTPS` by default. What this means is that if you are using unencrypted `HTTP` requests in your app, the app will work fine in all versions(lower) of Android except `Android P`.

**How to make it work on Android P?**

1. You just need to create a `network_security_config` file in the xml folder and then include it in the manifest in the following manner.

*The `network_security_config` file looks like this.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">nikit19.github.io</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Add it in Manifest as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
                    ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

2. Simply use this in Manifest inside application

   ```
   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think i have been fool around for few days as the problem is solved :
I just forgot to add   `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`  in my manifest file.Now it works well
Since it did not show in my logcat error i have been fooling myself.
Thanks everyone for your comment.

Comment: It did show in your logcat. You're printing the stack trace for the Exception it was throwing: `catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`. That's why I suggested that you look further up in your logcat.